# Controller inheritance not working with controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So essentially the HTML looks like:

```
<data>
    <definition-data></definition-data>
</data>
```

In my data template file I have the following, which works:

```
<div ng-controller="dataCtrl as dataitems" ng-cloak>
    {{dataitems.loadItem}}
</div>
```

In my definition-data template, I tried to access dataitems.loadItem, but wasn't able to despite it inheriting the parent scope of data.

I tried:

```
<div ng-controller="definitionCtrl as definition" ng-cloak>
    <h3>{{dataitems.loadItem}}</h3>
</div>
```

Which didn't make it appear.

In my data controller file, I have:

```
var self = this;
self.loadItem = 3;
return self;
```

Edit: Definition data directive as requested

```
angular.module('s').directive('definitionData', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      templateUrl: 'definition/definition.tpl.html',
      scope: {}
   };
});
```

Data Directive:

```
angular.module('s').directive('data', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,
      scope : true,
      templateUrl: 'data/data.tpl.html'
   };
});
```

Comment: You need to show the directive definition for `definitionData` directive

Comment: And, it looks like you are capitalizing the I in `dataItems`, but your `dataCtrl` controller alias is all lower-case `dataitems`.

Comment: Good catch, new dev, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: You would also need to provide definition for `data` directive, now that I think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a number of things going on here that I think are incorrect (I'm only assuming what you may be after).

**First**, you should not declare app controllers within the template of the directive. It beats the purpose of re-usability of the directive. Either use a controller within directive's definition (if the controller only deals with the functionality of the directive), or - if the controller belongs to the app, declare `ng-controller` on the directive itself (not the template). I'm assuming you want the latter, so do this:

```
<data ng-controller="dataCtrl as dataitems">
    <definition-data ng-controller="definitionCtrl as definition"></definition-data>
</data>
```

**Second**, when you declare the directive's scope like so:

```
{ ...
  scope: {}
}
```

you are creating an isolate scope. If you intend to inherit the parent's scope, define `scope: true`.

**Third**, you need to actually place the transcluded element somewhere in your `<data>` directive template:

```
<div ng-controller="dataCtrl as dataitems">
    {{dataitems.loadItem}}
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

**And finally**, transcluded element (`definition-data`) gets the scope of the parent of the transcluding directive (`data`), but your `dataCtrl` controller is defined on the element itself. (I actually expected the `dataCtrl` to be in the scope, but it's not).

So, if you did something like this, it would work:

```
<div ng-controller="dataCtrl as dataitems">
  <data>
    <definition-data ng-controller="definitionCtrl as definition"></definition-data>
  </data>
</div>
```

Since I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, I can't give you a better answer. This answer just deals with the symptoms of what you're facing.